# ASP.net C3 IF condition ispostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, isnullorempty, ispostback

Can anyone explain to me what this conditions means, thanks in advance.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"]) && !Page.IsPostBack)
{
    code = Request["code"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: the code is checking whether a querystring parameter "code" is passed to the page during the first loading of the page. Page.IsPostBack is used to check whether the page is loaded for first time or a call back from the client side ajax call. Request["code"] is the querystring parameter like http://mypage.com/test?code=abc, to check whether a parameter of such is being passed to the page. hope this helps

Comment: @JohnVega, do you want us to teach you basic .net / c# coding..? if you are not familiar with `string.IsNullOrEmpty` function do a google search also do the same for `IsPostBack`

Comment: im just a bit confused with the exclamation symbol, is !Page.IsPostBack the same as Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: the exclamation denotes "not", if (not)Page.IsPostBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supplied Snippet will check for two conditions 1. `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"])` and 2. `!Page.IsPostBack` and Will execute the statement `code = Request["code"].ToString();` only if both the conditions ware true.

More Details about the two conditions mentioned in the `if()`:

**1. `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"])`:**

[`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)  Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string. It will return true if the value parameter is null or an empty string (""); otherwise, false.

**2. `Page.IsPostBack`:**

[`Page.IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback. It will return true if the page is being loaded in response to a client postback; otherwise, false.

Note : In both the conditions `!` symbol will negates the return value from the function. That means if `Page.IsPostBack()` returns `true` then `!Page.IsPostBack()` will convert it to `false` and wise versa.

**Summary:**

The code will check whether the query-string parameter "code" `(Request["code"])` is `null` or `empty`, and check whether it is a postback event or not, only when the first condition is true(ie., Request["code"] have some value other than `""`).

Comment: is !Page.IsPostBack the same as Page.IsPostBack without the exclamation symbol?

Comment: No, Both are different. if `Page.IsPostBack()` returns `true` then `!Page.IsPostBack()` will convert it to `false` and wise versa.  see updates in the answer

Comment: Then that means:
IF !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"])   - contains a value its TRUE
IF !Page.IsPostBack - is a post back - is FALSE 
????

Answer (score 0):

if (ispostback is not true)means the page dose not load from the **server control** and (request["Code"] is not null) means it exist 
and (request["Code"] is not empty) means it's not equal ""